# c++ error C2064 for nested bind in C++ template

Tags: c++, bind

If I compile the code below, I get an:
microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(58): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

In the call to accumulate algorithm, if I change the code to `function<double(double, Position const&) > f = bind(sum, placeholders::_1, bind(mem_fn(&Position::getBalance), placeholders::_2));double sum = accumulate(balances.begin(), balances.end(), 0., f);` everything compiles fine. I also tried to use a non member function, but it doesn't work neither.

```
class Position
{
private:
    double m_balance;
public:
    Position(double balance) :
        m_balance(balance)
    {}

    double getBalance() const
    {
        return m_balance;
    }
};

static double sum(double v1, double v2)
{
    return v1 + v2;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::vector< Position > balances;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        balances.push_back(Position(i));
    }

    double sum = accumulate(balances.begin(), balances.end(), 0., bind(sum, placeholders::_1, bind(mem_fn(&Position::getBalance), placeholders::_2)));
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the return type of std::bind:

    "A function object of unspecified type T, for which std::is_bind_expression<T>::value == true"

The msvc doesn't know what type it is, so it can not evalutate it to a 2 arg function.

Comment: Thanks @Krapow. I don't think they are related. But I learned from your comment the return type of bind is unspecified.

Comment: I have made a mistake by naming the variable the same way as the function. After renaming the function 'sum' to 'sumUp', the problem disappears.

Answer (score 4):

This will fix it:

```
double sum = accumulate(balances.cbegin(), 
                        balances.cend(), 
                        0.0 , 
                        std::bind(std::plus<>(), 
                                  placeholders::_1,
                                  std::bind(&Position::getBalance, placeholders::_2)));
```

or we could be kind to our fellow programmers:

```
auto add_balance = [](auto x, auto& position) {
  return x + position.getBalance();
};

double sum = accumulate(balances.cbegin(), 
                        balances.cend(), 
                        0.0 , 
                        add_balance);
```

Or of course we can inline the lambda. There's no performance difference. Which one seems clearer will be a matter of personal preference.

```
double sum = accumulate(balances.cbegin(), 
                        balances.cend(), 
                        0.0 , 
                        [](auto x, auto& position) 
                        {
                          return x + position.getBalance();
                        });
```

Or we can write a complex functor to do a similar job. This was the pre-lambda way:

```
template<class Op>
struct PositionOp
{
  using mfp_type = double (Position::*)() const;

  PositionOp(Op op, mfp_type mfp) : op(op), mfp(mfp) {}

  template<class T>
  auto operator()(T x, const Position& pos) const {
    return op(x, (pos.*mfp)());
  }

  Op op;
  mfp_type mfp;
};

template<class Op>
auto position_op(Op op, double (Position::*mfp)() const)
{
  return PositionOp<Op>(op, mfp);
}
```

...

```
double sum = accumulate(balances.cbegin(), 
                        balances.cend(), 
                        0.0 , 
                        position_op(std::plus<>(), &Position::getBalance));
```

... but I hope you'll agree that this is ghastly.

Comment: Thus sayeth Scott Meyers, "Prefer lambda expressions over `std::bind`."

Comment: @John yes he's right. The assembly that comes out of the lambda version is faultless.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges. After reading your answer.I find out that the problem is the variable 'sum' has the same name as function 'sum'. After renaming the function to sumUp, the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks @John. In my case, I have a lot of different types : Position, Balance, Price etc., that I want to sum up a field. I don't like to write for each of them a lambda expression. But you are right that lambda is more readable in this case.

Comment: @user1037443 i understand of course. Remember though, that it is a fact that during its life, every line of code is read more often than it is written. Saving a little typing can seem like time saved, but it is not. If there is the slightest mistake in any of those complex bind expressions you write - and they are complex, the proof of that is that you needed to ask advice on writing them - then any time you save on a few keystrokes will be easily outweighed by the time spent debugging them. `bind` was useful before we had lambdas (it was invented in boost). It's outdated now.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @RichardHodges. I agree that a few keystrokes is not worth of the time used for debugging.